# compile error; method or data not found

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

this below code are is working fine in laptop, but in my office desktop i am unable to run the program. Error is method or data not found.
Please provide me a solution.

Private Sub cmdGenRep_Click()

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    sbStatusBar.Panels(1).Text = "Developed by: xxx"
    sbStatusBar.Panels(2).Text = "Ver: " & App.Major & "." & App.Minor & "." & App.Revision
    tabSales.Tab = 0
    OptQReg.Value = True

    cboMonth.AddItem "January"
    cboMonth.AddItem "February"
    cboMonth.AddItem "March"
    cboMonth.AddItem "April"
    cboMonth.AddItem "May"
    cboMonth.AddItem "June"
    cboMonth.AddItem "July"
    cboMonth.AddItem "August"
    cboMonth.AddItem "September"
    cboMonth.AddItem "October"
    cboMonth.AddItem "November"
    cboMonth.AddItem "December"

    cboMonth.ListIndex = Val(Format(Date, "mm")) - 1
    txtYear = Format(Date, "YYYY")

    Dim Tdate As String
    Dim Fdate As Date
    Tdate = "01/" & Format(Date, "MMM/YY")
    Fdate = Format(Tdate, "DD/MMM/YY")
    optQRep.Value = True
    optComp.Value = True
    optEntry.Value = True
    DTPstDate.Value = Fdate
    DTPEndDate.Value = Format(Date, "DD/MMM/YY")

    cboScope.AddItem "ALL"
    cboScope.AddItem "STEEL+CLADDING"
    cboScope.AddItem "CLADDING ONLY"
    cboScope.AddItem "STEEL ONLY"
    cboScope.ListIndex = 0

    pathTmpl = "C:\templates\"
    pathQregister = "C:\register\"
    pathJobRegister = "C:\register\"

End Sub
```

Comment: You didn't indicate which code line generates error and didn't tag the question properly (Excel?) I think your desktop just doesn't have reference to required library. Check for rows with `MISSING` word in references (Tools->References)

Comment: sbStatusBar.Panels(1).Text = "Developed by: xxx" erreor is showing in this line.... same reference kept in lap & desktop... pc configurations are also same.... vb6 is the application using... but in desktop both office excel 2003 & 2007 installed, but in lap only office 2007 installed

Comment: Check how defined sbStatusBar, probably it uses external library.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be due compatibility issues with excel versions.  Here is the sure way to change statusbar text and return it to original when the script is finished

```
sub statusBarChange()
   oldStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar 
   Application.DisplayStatusBar = True 
   Application.StatusBar = "Please be patient..." 
   Workbooks.Open filename:="LARGE.XLS" 
   Application.StatusBar = False 
   Application.DisplayStatusBar = oldStatusBar
end sub
```

From: [Microsoft.Com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835916.aspx)